# Why can't I run Java Web Start Applications?

Tags: firefox, java, browser

I have Ubuntu 12.10 for x86-64 on my PC and I'm trying to run a `.jnlp` file. I've installed Java 7 and the Java plugin for Mozilla Firefox manually (because there is no `.deb` package for Java 7 for Ubuntu).

Whenever I double click a `.jnlp` file, Firefox is opened and it gives me the option of opening the file with Firefox or saving it. If I click save, it download the file I'm trying to run, and if I click open with Firefox web browser, it opens another tab and asks me again (in the new tab) to either open or save.

I used to run the exact same file on Debian, so what should I do to run this file on Ubuntu?

Comment: Go to (Firefox) Preferences --> Applications --> JNLP file --> Use other

Now go to your Java 7 disrectory --> bin --> javaws

This will open your jnlp file 

---------------

Note - You can use Icedtea for opening jnlp files.

Answer (score 18):

First install the **icedtea-8-plugin** package (or later version) that include the java browser-plugin and the javaws webstart tool that can launch .jnlp files.

Use javaws to open the downloaded .jnlp file.

Comment: To install  **icedtea-7-plugin** type `sudo apt-get install icedtea-7-plugin`.

Comment: icedtea-7-plugin is not found anymore. Now you should install icedtea-8-plugin

Comment: `apt-cache search "icedtea-.*-plugin"` to find appropriate version.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried verifying that java is working properly?  You can use this link to see if it is.  http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp?detect=jre
If not, You'll have to get it enabled properly.  I'm still a bit of a Noob but I had that same problem.  Regards

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 19.10, use:

```
sudo apt install icedtea-netx
```

Comment: This package exists not only since 19.10 but for all currently supported Ubuntu releases (at least 16.04 and newer). Check e.g. https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=icedtea-netx

Answer (score 0):

In directory  `/usr/lib/firefox-addons/plugins`

Create symbolic link

```
ln -s /usr/share/javaclient/jre1.8.0_121/lib/amd64/libnpjp2.so
```

Go to (Firefox) *Preferences* --> *Applications* --> *JNLP file* --> *Use other*

Now go to your Java 8 directory --> *bin* --> *javaws*

This will open your `jnlp` file

Credit Din for the firefox preferences.

Answer (score 0):

Apart of installing the OpenJDK 8 JRE, you may need to set the proper JRE in the IcedTea-web control panel (there's an application icon in your desktop environment). It could default to OpenJDK 11, so you need to set it up from there, in jvm settings, and select a path for the 8 version.